# SQL migrate data from one table to another on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling to write a migration from one table to another. I had a table `vault`. Now I created a new table `company`. The `vault` table contained some data about the "company" which I now want to "move" into the specific `company` table.

1. Each `Company` can have it's multiple `Vault`s, and it **always** has at least one `Vault`.
2. Each `Vault` references exactly one company.
3. The `company` references a `master_vault` which is `Vault` with name "Master".

So I want to write a migration that will fill my new `company` table with the data from the `Vault`, and also set the `master_vault` of the company to that with the name "Master".

I tried something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  id                VARCHAR         NOT NULL,
  created_at        TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
  updated_at        TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
  master_vault_id   VARCHAR         NOT NULL,
  company_name      VARCHAR         NULL,
  country           VARCHAR(2)      NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (master_vault_id) REFERENCES vault (id)
);


INSERT INTO company (id, created_at, updated_at, master_vault_id, company_name, country)
SELECT company_id, NOW(), NOW(), id, company_name, country
FROM vault
WHERE vault.name = 'Master';
```

However, this migration failed:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"company_pkey\"\n  Detail: Key (id)=(123456) already exists
```

What did I do wrong? Someone please help me with this SQL.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but: do **not** store numbers in `varchar` columns. Use `integer` or `bigint`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name IDs are actually strings. Could you help store the same company only once? Is there something to tweak in the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each Company can have it's multiple Vaults, and it always has at least one Vault.

This means you have multiple values for `vault.company_id` in your `vault` table. So you need to get only the distinct values from the ID column.

To pick only one company_id from the vault table, you can use PostgreSQL's `distinct on ()` operator:

```
INSERT INTO company (id, created_at, updated_at, master_vault_id, company_name, country)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (company_id) company_id, NOW(), NOW(), id, company_name, country
FROM vault
WHERE vault.name = 'Master'
ORDER BY company_id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/AROU80315

Comment: Btw why do we need ORDER BY here?

Comment: @Whizzil: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Your error mentions that there is a key violation. You declared `id` as a primary key that does not allow duplicate values.

**123456** already exists in your table, so you will not be able to insert the same value again into that column.

Comment: Well I know, but how I can solve that in my SQL given my requirements? I don't want the same company twice, obviously.